# AuthenticationForm 'The view account.views.login_view didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.'

Tags: python, django

I have a problem with `AuthenticationForm()`, when login and passwords are correct everything works correct, but when I want to cause an error with wrong password or login instead getting 'incorrect login or password' error, I get the following error page:
[image: error page]

My *views.py* code:

```
    def login_view(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form =AuthenticationForm(data=request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            #log in the user
             return redirect('Product_list')
    else:
        form = AuthenticationForm()
        return render(request, 'account/login.html', {'form': form})
```

My template code:

```
{%block content%}

<form class="login-form" method="POST">
    {%csrf_token%}
   {{ form.as_p }}
    <input type="submit" value="Logowanie">
</form>
<div id="signup">
    <a href="http://127.0.0.1:8000/account/signup/">
        Jeżeli nie masz jeszcze konta zarejestruj się: <input type="submit" value="Rejestracja">
    </a>
</div>

{%endblock%}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your view if the form is valid you return `return redirect('Product_list')` but is not valid you're not returning anything.

Try to change your code to:

```
def login_view(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form =AuthenticationForm(data=request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            #log in the user
             return redirect('Product_list')
        return render(request, 'account/login.html', {'form': form})
    else:
        form = AuthenticationForm()
        return render(request, 'account/login.html', {'form': form})
```

or even better

```
def login_view(request):
    form = AuthenticationForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = AuthenticationForm(data=request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            #log in the user
             return redirect('Product_list')    
    return render(request, 'account/login.html', {'form': form})
```

Comment: Thanks, for showing where I made mistake. Its funny that in Sign Up view i had this correct but in Login view it was incorrect and I didn't see this.

Comment: Any time, glad to help.